# website specific search within an android app

Tags: android, eclipse

*Is there a way to search a specific website that i assign using a search box within my app. with out searching the web and without the user changing what website to search?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the website. For instance a website that allows the developer to get a XML responds, as a result of the search request.

You can then easily parse the XML and feed it to your app.

Comment: You can parse the response HTML page source. But if the owner decides to change the structure of the HTML page, it may cause problems.